# How to add items rows to a listview WPF and VB.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

Im getting crazy with it. It is so easy in windows form, but in wpf it seems to be different.
Every example i find is in C# and i cant addapt it.
Well, this is the code i have. Atm, i have just defined the columns:

```
 'diseño de las columnas
        Dim item As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem
        Dim Mi_Lista As GridView = New GridView
        Mi_Lista.AllowsColumnReorder = True

        Dim cine As New GridViewColumn()
        Dim Si3d As New GridViewColumn
        cine.Header = "Cine"
        cine.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("Cine")
        Si3d.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("si3D")
        cine.Width = 140
        Si3d.Header = "3D"
        Si3d.Width = 50
        Mi_Lista.Columns.Add(cine)
        Mi_Lista.Columns.Add(Si3d)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that every code example is in C# should be telling you something about VB.NET's usefulness...

Comment: 1. You could use one of the C#-to-VB converters to convert the example code (ask Google about these converters). 2. I don't understand what you are trying to do: You talk about "adding item *rows* ", but your code seems to add *columns* ...

Comment: Matti, VB.NET and C# are functionally equivalent in most areas including I think everything that WPF is concerned with.  If he or his team are more comfortable with VB than with C#, then VB is going to be a lot more "useful" to them than C#; and it can easily do what he needs it to.  Knocking VB's "usefulness" is poor advice.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Add ListViewItems to the ListView.Items property.  This is the WinForms way but is not idiomatic in WPF.
2. Set the ListView.ItemsSource property.  WPF will then *create* a row for each entry in the ItemsSource collection.  *You will not need to Dim ListViewItem objects yourself in this case.*  This is idiomatic WPF.

To do option 2, write something like this:

```
Dim data As ObservableCollection(Of Something) = New ObservableCollection(Of Something)
' Populate the collection
lv.ItemsSource = data
```

Note that here `lv` is your ListView, not your GridView.  Also you would normally define your ListView and columns in XAML rather than code, e.g.

```
<ListView Name="lv">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Cine"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Cine}"
                      Width="140" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, i got it some days ago, thanks.
For future users:

```
Public Sub LlenarLista(ByVal película As String)
    ' MessageBox.Show(película)
    Dim dtLista As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim connetionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=Cinépolis.mdb"
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
    connection.Open()
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Cines.Nombre as nombre, Películas.Título, Proyecciones.[3D] AS p3d, Cines.web, Cines.Ubicacion as Ubicación, Cines.Parking FROM Películas INNER JOIN (Cines INNER JOIN Proyecciones ON Cines.IdCine = Proyecciones.IDCine) ON Películas.IDPelícula = Proyecciones.IDPelícula WHERE (((Películas.Título)='" & película & "')); ", connection)
    da.Fill(dt)
    dtLista = dt
    lvCines.DataContext = dtLista
    lvCines.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, New Binding)

    connection.Close()
```

Y el diseño:

```
            <GridView ColumnHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource estiloCabecera}" >
                <GridViewColumn    Header="Cine" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding nombre}"   />

                <GridViewColumn Header="3D" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding p3d}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Web" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding web}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: C#

this is the starting point:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1

C# to VB.Net:
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/